# Java 8 is official, right?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

Java.com doesn't seem to hype it so much, but to my knowledge Java 8 is official, and Java programmers had better catch up.

**Destroy [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8). It's just [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).**

Comment: Why had java programmers better catch up? There are plenty of developers working in an enterprise environment where getting to play with java 8  (or even java 7) is a pipe dream.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of tags that have a version number. They're not here in anticipation of the official announcement for the next release, they're here to say that a question is actually *specific* to that version.

There's plenty of Java questions that are applicable to all, or multiple versions of Java. [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) should be for what's specific to Java 8, but doesn't apply to other versions.

Typically, a question tagged [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) would try to make use of some of the features that were not in previous versions (or where the behaviour differs), whereas a question tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) would be more general.

Answer (score 9):

There are dozens upon dozens of version specific tags.  Here are a few I know of that exist off the top of my head

- [c#-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0) and each of its predecessors [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0), [c#-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0), [c#-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0)
- [php-5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.3)
- [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)
- And let's not forget [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7)

The version specific tags are extremely useful because it allows for the author of the question to provide some idea of the scope of their features.  If they are asking a question about version specific features of a language, then it would be good if they could identify the version to make it easier for people searching for question.

Similarly, if someone is confined to a specific version of the language for any reason (maybe they are supporting legacy code, maybe they don't have access to the newer version), then it is useful to identify any specific constraints they are working with.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, perhaps Java 8 has been released, but that doesn’t mean there are still people using earlier versions. Until Java 8 is not only officially released but also mainstream and common, people may be reluctant to give answers that use functionality introduced in Java 8. The [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) tag is an explicit message to answerers that yes, they have upgraded, and Java 8 answers are acceptable or even preferred. This is the same rationale used to justify [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).